# Using JSON with ASP.net vs IIS

Tags: c#, json, iis

I am in a situation where I possibly can influence a decision about some web service work on the C# side and need some nice info (ammunition) that I can use to choose what I think would be better(JSON).

Could anyone give me any help as to the pros and cons of each? One of things that I like about JSON is that is it much cleaner to maintain, it supports any web browser(i think) and it supports(i am pretty sure) the ability to send non-primitive objects across the pipe. If IIS can do all of those things then please inform me differently. thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you going to run you ASP.Net on?

Comment: are you asking if JSON should be used 'instead' of IIS ? ASP.NET runs on IIS and JSON can be used by ASP.NET over IIS...

Comment: ok then - i was unaware that ASP.NET could use JSON over IIS. I wasn't real sure about it. I am used to using things like apache or glassfish so this is kind of new to me. Does JSON in fact support non-primitive types to be passed through the pipe? Support for UDTs are going to be very important

Comment: I think you may be unclear on your terminology here. JSON is a data format. You have to have some code to generate and/or transmit it to your web page's javascript. IIS is web server software. Web pages and web services run on it. Those web pages and web services can generate JSON to return to calling pages.

Comment: [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a data format. [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) is a web server.

Comment: thanks for the clarification on that. I guess the question would be why would you not choose to use JSON? That is why not just use XML? I am trying to come up with a clear concise reason for going down a certain route with web services. thanks -

Comment: @usmsci, that depends on the services.  XML and JSON are tools.  Neither is inherently better than the other at all tasks.  Also, if you know so little about IIS, ASP.Net, and JSON, are you sure you should be helping make this decision?  No disrespect intended.

Comment: no problem, well i was asked to provide feedback so I was going to attempt to provide some based on what feedback I got on here and what limited knowledge that I could get on the web. All this was needed by COB so this is short notice. thanks again for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If the decision is for the data transport, is best to use **JSON** than xml, since the footprint is smaller, the translation from the string to the object is easily supported in all languages (javascript, C#), you can use **JSON** services to communicate cross domains (which fails if you are using an XML web service).
a non primitive data type is transformed to a **JSON** string, you can have really complex objects in **JSON** format, the only issue you may find is the Date transformation, but if the code is only for your company, that may not pose a problem since the serialization and de-serialization will be the same.
you can find the description of **JSON** [here.](http://www.json.org/) 

 To be able to get more help you will have to be more specific on what do you want to do.